# developing a native mobile app for blackberry os5 +

Tags: java, blackberry

I am coming from PHP and have a tiny understanding of Java, though am still learning it. I want to develop an app for blackberry which will work with os' 5,6,7 . What the steps to take to do this, where can i get the right sources to learn just enough Java to develop apps for blackberry and how do i get started ?

Comment: I think BB OS 5-7 are really outdated. Sure you want to start with these old versions? The SDK for BBOS 7.1 can be found here: http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/

Comment: Yes i do want to start with these old versions, but also i want the app to be able to support newer versions 6,7. and i know bb10 is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: You might want to drop support for OS 5, and have a look at [Webworks](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html). Coming from web development, you might find it easier to start.

Comment: @smith i don't want the webworks thing, tried it before its very slow

Answer (score 2):

The place to start is the java microsite:

[BB Java microsite](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/)

From there you will be able to download the SDK, including support for OS 7.1.  In the Tools section you will also find instructions for downloading the JRE for OS 5.0, which is what you want to use, since OS 5.0 applications will also run on OS 6 and OS 7.

The learning "just enough Java" is a tricky part.  In fact, the BB Java is based on Java 1.3/1.4, i.e. a really old level of Java.  So all the new java books and courses will teach you things you can't do.  So in fact the best thing to do might be to buy an old Java book and work through the first few chapters of that.  You don't want to go anything other than base java nor anything UI related since that is different on the BB platform.

I don't recommend cutting your first java program on the BB since there are some 'magic incantations' that you execute to run java programs on the BB.  So learn the Java basics on a platform you already know (PC?).

Once you get here, then try out some samples (Hello World!!!!) on the BB.  And review the documentation on the microsite.  It is significantly better now than when I started coding for BB!

I found Eclipse (the IDE) a little 'strange' at first, and bought a cheap Eclipse book to get me started with it.  You might consider the same.

I would also recommend a BB Java book, there are a few, search for "Blackberry Development".  For you though, don't get the Wargo book, you want a code book like the one by Rizk or Foust (my preference but the Risk book is fine too).

And when you do hit problems (and you will!) then search, here and the official BB forum at least.  You are coming (very) late to a party that is in fact, as you have been told, winding up.  But that means most of the issues have already been found so I'm guessing better than 90% of any problems you find will have Threads and resolutions that will help if you search.

Hope this helps.